# Expressing a Binomial Series as an Integral

Tags: integration, summation, binomial-theorem

I have the following series at hand and I am tasked to rewrite it as an integral. This is what I've done so far. However I'm having trouble bringing my expression into the form of the given options.

> Rewrite the given Binomial Series as an Integral.$$\dfrac{n\choose 0}{n(n+1)}-\dfrac{n\choose 1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots (n+1) \text{ terms}$$
>
> 1.) $\int_0^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n+1}\mathrm dx$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  2.)\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n-1}\mathrm dx$

**My Attempt**:

Clearly this would come from the Binomial expansion of $(1-x)^n$ with a term of $x^{\alpha}$ multiplied and has to be integrated twice. The $\alpha$ most likely seems to be $(n-1)$. And so I would write the series as $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n}\mathrm dx$$

How to bring this into the form as in the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telescoping enables us to manage the calculation with one integral only. We  obtain for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j\frac{1}{(n+j)(n+j+1)}}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j\left(\frac{1}{n+j}-\frac{1}{n+j+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j\int_{0}^1\left(x^{n+j-1}-x^{n+j}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^1\left(x^{n-1}-x^n\right)\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^jx^j\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\left(x^{n-1}-x^n\right)(1-x)^n\,dx\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n+1}\,dx}
\end{align*}

and       the claim follows.